# How to complete or stall a save button operation using "Are you sure you want to proceed" modal with yes and no button in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a link in an HTML table which when clicked calls this Rails controller function :

### Controller:

```rb
    def match
        render :partial => 'myview/match.js.erb'
    end
```

The above controller calls this js partial:

### _match.js.erb

```rb
    $('#match_' + <%=@debit.id%>).hide().after('<%= j render("match") %>');
```

The above js partial calls the `erb` below:

### _match.html.erb

```rb
  <%= form_for(@debit, remote: true, html: { id: 'match_form' }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :match_id, style: "width:82px" %>
    <br/><br/>
    <%= button_tag 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', id: 'match_submit', style: "width:38px;padding:0px" %> 
    <%= button_tag 'Cancel', class: 'btn btn-secondary', id: 'match_cancel', style: "width:52px;padding:0px" %>
  <% end %>
```

As shown the above partial displays a `text field` with 2 buttons `Save` and `Cancel`.

Now, when the user enters a value and clicks on `Save`, I would like to do some minor validation.

1. If the validation succeeds, I would like the `Save` operation to complete (which means the text field and the `Save` and `Cancel` buttons would disappear and the original HTML link would re-appear with the new value entered in the text field [now if this link with the new number is clicked, then the text field with `Save` and `Cancel` button would re-appear] i.e., the controller function `def match` should be allowed to complete)
2. If the validation fails, I would like to display a popup which gives a warning something like `Are you sure you want to proceed with this value?` along with 2 buttons `Yes` and `No`.

   a) If the user clicks `Yes`, I would like the same thing to happen what happened in case 1 above
   b) If the user clicks `No`, then the text field should stay unclosed along with the `Save` and `Cancel` buttons.

How can I achieve this please? What would be the simplest approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

The laziest way to do something similar would be to use the old [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) gem.

You should be able to craft the behavior you want using the callbacks they provide:

```
// You will need to require 'jquery-ui' for this to work
window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.fail = function(element, message, callback) {
  callback();
  if (element.data('valid') !== false) {
    element.parent().find('.message').hide().show('slide', {direction: "left", easing: "easeOutBounce"}, 500);
  }
}

window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.pass = function(element, callback) {
  // Take note how we're passing the callback to the hide()
  // method so it is run after the animation is complete.
  element.parent().find('.message').hide('slide', {direction: "left"}, 500, callback);
}

.message {
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

div.field_with_errors div.ui-effects-wrapper {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to write a good amount of JavaScript to check all of the states of interest and draw the modal.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery validate](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-plugin-a-confirm-alert-on-submit) You can simply achieve the desired result by using jQuery Validation Plugin like this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#new_user').validate({
    errorClass:'error',

  rules: {
    'user[first_name]':{
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages:{
    'user[first_name]':{
      required: 'This field is required.'
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function( ){
    answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?");
    if (answer == true){
      form.submit( );
    }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }

  });
});
```

And trigger the above JS after

> $('#match_' + <%=@debit.id%>).hide().after('<%= j render("match") %>');

this line in **_match.js.erb**